# Width 100% but extra width is making scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, width

This is so weird but gonna try anyway. 
So i have this carousel with 100%. My screen size is 1366px. My web site is vertically long so the scroll automatically appear. And it makes the web more like 1350px. But my carousel still taking 1366px width and having scroll on the bottom. 
And the funny part is When i try to inspect, the bottom scroll disappears. And my width is 1350px when i inspect. I've been trying to fix it for hours.

And my last hope is you guys. So please help me.

Edit: uploaded 
http://leoxid.com/test/home_page.html
Oh and please check it on Chrome. Did't do any other browser fix :D

Comment: It's on localhost. But i can make some screen shots. http://i42.tinypic.com/2u6h2yw.png http://i44.tinypic.com/2yo5to9.png

Comment: i got it uploaded... Please help me guys... http://leoxid.com/test/home_page.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your jQuery is executing before the page is fully loaded. This can be solved by executing your code on `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ });`, or, if that doesn't work, with a timeout:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(function() {
                $('#foo2').carouFredSel({
                    width       : "100%",
                    align       : "center",
                    auto        : false,
                    prev        : '#prev2',
                    next        : '#next2',
                    pagination  : "#pager2",
                    scroll      : 3,
                    items       : {
                        visible : 9,
                    }
            });
        });
    }, 500);
});
</script>
```

The timeout might not be needed, but just to be sure.

This is how it should look, on the place where you call the function for your carousel.

The $(document).ready() waits till the document is fully loaded. The setTimeout waits an extra half a second just to be sure everything is really loaded. (useful in the case of slow loading images).

If the timeout is overkill, you can remove the following two lines

```
setTimeout(function(){
}, 500);
```

Comment: Did you try my suggestion yet?

Comment: i'm not really good with jquery and don't know where to put it. and <script>jQuery(document).ready(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do your magic
    }, 500);
});</script> not working for me hehe... sorry please

Comment: Thank you btw. But it changes nothing so it must be something else. Can't really found out what...

Comment: I take it you have solved your problem? If not, I will take a look at it at a later time. I'm afraid I don't have the time or resources at this moment to investigate further. I will later on (within a day)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when the carousel was initialized (onready?), the contents inside haven't been fully loaded and its total height was less than the total available browser client area height. And during initialization the carousel 'fixes' its width to the one it got in a computed fashion.

Once solution is to apply `overflow: scroll` to your body, so the 16px or so at the far right is always taken, even before the carousel initializes.